# Как преобразовать строку в изображение?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.

На работе есть программа, которая сохраняет фотографию человека в текстовый файл.

> `-9j-4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD-2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA...`

И так далее. Там много символов. Как мне обратно преобразовать символы в изображение?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за программа?
Обычно для преобразования бинарных данных в текст используется используется алгоритм base64.

Comment: Суть не в программе, а в том, как перевести в изображение, пойду разбираться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы перевести поток символов в изображение, нужно знать алгоритм, по которому изображением было переведено в поток символов. Пример для 16-ричного представления.

В hex

```
f = open("from.jpg", "rb")
i = f.read()
s = binascii.hexlify(i)
```

Из hex

```
ff = open("from.jpg", "r")
ii = ff.read()
ss = binascii.unhexlify(ii)
```

Comment: В моем случае помог модуль base64.
z - строка символов.

    with open('12.jpeg', 'wb') as f_pdf :
    pdfname = base64.b64decode(z,'!-')
    f_pdf.write(pdfname)

Answer (score 0):

С модулем base64

`z` - строковое представление изображения

Однако тут надо также знать алгоритм, по которому было переведено изображение. У автора 64-ричное представление, но есть модули `base16`, `base32`, `base64`, `base85`. Подробнее можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)

```
import base64

with open('12.jpeg', 'wb') as f_pdf :
  pdfname = base64.b64decode(z,'!-') 
  f_pdf.write(pdfname)
```

Решение взято из комментария автора вопроса и дополненно